# JSONSerialization did't serialised data as server send

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, api

JSONSerialization didn't serialise data as server send. It reverses turn the data. I use data filter API from backend. its send the accurate data, I've also checked in postman and android side but iOS code changes the response.

```swift
do {
    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: usableData, options: .mutableLeaves) as? [String: Any] {  

    }
} catch let error {
    OperationQueue.main.addOperation() {
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    }
}
```

But if i convert the data into string then its shows correct. WHY?

```swift
var jsonString : String?
jsonString = String.init(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

Comment: What error do you get? By the way `mutableLeaves` is completely useless in Swift.

Comment: then what is correct form please suggest? Actually i did't use any reading option.

Comment: I did't use any reading option.

Comment: do {

       if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: usableData, options: .[]) as? [String: Any] {  

  }
                 } catch let error {
                     OperationQueue.main.addOperation() {
                             SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                     }
                 }

Comment: No, I mean the beginning of `jsonString`. And add it to the question, not in the comments. Once again remove the `options` parameter, the default value is *no options*

Comment: Nothing change @vadian. i use all of this option. Basically API sends the data in Dictionary form.

Comment: do `} catch  { print(error) }` and attach the error also do `print(jsonString)`

Comment: did't get any error @Sh_Khan. Problem is JSONSerialization reverse turn the data

Comment: If you want to get help either **print** and show the `error` as Sh_Khan suggested or show the beginning of `jsonString`.

Comment: Optional("{\"status\":\"ok\",\"listings\":{\"14573\":{\"id\":\"14573\",\"lat\":\"\",\"lng\":\"\",\"property_lat\":\"1.3363935779867\",\"property_lng\":\"103.8651122037\",\"hasOH\":\"0\",\"price\":\"0\",\"listing_name\":

Comment: The output seems to be correct. But  `usableData` might not be equal to `data`. What is the string output of `usableData`?

Comment: same above @vadian

Comment: please help if you got anything. Thanks

Comment: `Dictionary` is orderless, you just need to access the required values using keys.

Comment: but server sends the data in correct form because i use data sorting with API. @Kamran

Comment: Dictionary has no order. Array of dictionaries would

Comment: The partial response you shared, i can not see any list in it where you need sorting. You may need to share complete response to get better help.

Comment: should i need to change the format in server side? @Scriptable

Comment: Optional("{\"status\":\"ok\",\"listings\":{\"14573\":{\"id\":\"14573\",\"lat\":\"\",\"lng\":\"\",\"property_lat\":\"1.3363935779867\",\"property_lng\":\"103.8651122037\",\"hasOH\":\"0\",\"price\":\"0\",\"listing_name\": –

in Listing params have multiple keys like 14573 @Kamran

Comment: should i need to change the format in server side? @Scriptable

Comment: @jaskiratjd You are overthinking, please try this [tutorial](https://learnappmaking.com/codable-json-swift-how-to/) and apply to your JSON response. You can also get free code for all the Models and parsing using [this](https://app.quicktype.io/) web app. Once you learn the parsing then you will realize why you need to correct your response structure on the backend i.e, making `listings` as an `Array` of `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've got the solution. Server sends the data more than 100 keys in dictionary which is incorrect form, with this format our json serialisation could not able to serialised the data as we got from server.so we have decided to change the structure from dictionary to Array.

**Incorrect form**

```
1025{
id:1025
name:xyz
area:23123
}
1026{
id:1026
name:xyz
area:23123
}
1027{
id:1027
name:xyz
area:23123
}
```

**Correct Form**

```
 [
    id:1025
    name:xyz
    area:23123
    ,
    id:1026
    name:xyz
    area:23123
    ,
    id:1027
    name:xyz
    area:23123
    ]
```